# Не запускается скрипт php cron

Tags: php, centos, cron

Не срабатывает php скрипт при выставлении задачи в кроне.
Php скрипт:

```
  <?php
    $fd = fopen("/var/www/html/my_cron.txt", "a"); 
    fwrite($fd, "Обращение к файлу - ".date("d.m.Y H:i")."\r\n"); 
    fclose($fd); 

$subject = "Подтверждение";

$to = "=?utf-8?B?". base64_encode('Пользователь'). "?= <". "mymail@mail.ru". ">";

$message = " 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Здравствуйте!</title> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <p>"."Тестовое сообщение"."</p> 
        <p>-----------------------------------------------------------</p> 

    </body> 
</html>";

$headers  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n";
$headers .= "From: Sender.Net <no-reply@sender.net>\r\n";

if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
    echo "code-modal";
} else {
    echo "Код не отправлен";
}
?>
```

Поставил задачу через `crontab -e`:

```
*/1 * * * * cd /var/www/html/dashboard_version/server/reg-auth/; /usr/bin/php endtariff-mail.php
```

В списке задач `crontab -l` задача отображается.

Команда  `which php` возвращает /usr/bin/php

При ручном выполнении через ssh команды `cd /var/www/html/dashboard_version/server/reg-auth/; /usr/bin/php endtariff-mail.php` скрипт выполняется и письмо приходит на почту и в файл пишется, что скрипт был выполнен, но при выставлении задачи в кроне ничего не происходит.

Comment: для начала стоит заменить бессмысленное `*/1` на осмысленное `*`

Comment: заменил, но ничего не изменилось

Comment: измениться и не должно было. это было «для начала». а дальше проверяйте работоспособность. `touch /путь/к/файлу` и `echo > /путь/к/файлу` вам в помощь.

Comment: touch также не срабатывает, время доступа к файлу не меняется.

Comment: задача звучит как `* * * * * touch /tmp/file` и файл `/tmp/file` не создаётся? значит, разбирайтесь с *crond* и пользователем, от имени которого создана задача.

Comment: причина оказалась банальной. я забыл запустить службу. спасибо за наводку по поводу crond.